# Questions on the word シクシク

Tags: words, onomatopoeia

I understand that the word シクシク is 擬声語/giseigo/onomatopoeia equivalent to the English "boo-hoo/boo-hoo-hoo."

> 恐怖でシクシク泣く
> : To whimper in fear
>
> 彼女はボーイフレンドに捨てられた時、あまりの惨めさにシクシクと泣いた。
> : She wailed in misery when her boyfriend dumped her.

However, I also see it as a qualifier for pain, but I can't tell what kind of pain it describes. Is it a pain so "gripping" as to make one sob, or is it a "dull" pain (which implies something more to be inconvenienced or annoyed by)?

> シクシクと痛みます
> : It is a dull pain.
>
> 胃がシクシク痛む
> : have a gripping pain in one's stomach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

シクシク implies continuing, moderate level of crying/pain. I don't know if their etymology is related but 雨がシトシト降る also means that a moderate (not too hard, but not soft either) level of rain continuously falls. Maybe this sound pattern is associated with moderate, continuing things in Japanese.

Comment: It looks like it is possibly derived from 頻く頻く.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that シクシク describes a dull, gripping pain as in 締め付けられるような痛み.

I've heard it used most often in [hospitals](http://www.city.iwaki.fukushima.jp/gaikokugo/dbps_data/_material_/gaikokugo/medicalGuidebook/Medical_Guidebook41-48.pdf) to describe pain that a patient may be having.

Since you are describing a feeling using onomatopoeia, its implied meaning might be a bit vague without sufficient context. It's akin to trying to describe your car problem to a mechanic by imitating the car when it experiences the problem. E.g. "When I go up the hill my car goes *Grunt* *Plunk* *Poot* *Che-Che-Che*"

鈍痛 might be more appropriate to refer to dull pain in general.