# "Boo" equivalent in Japanese?

Tags: expressions, colloquial-language, english-to-japanese

Is there a disappointed or sad "boo" equivalent in Japanese?

Kind of like:

> *Person 1:* Hey man, can I borrow 10 dollars?
>   *Person 2:* Nah, I don't have any change.
>   *Person 1:* Boo, now I don't have enough to go to the concert.

Comment: Could always try ブー ;)

Comment: Disappointed or sad...?  Do you mean like トホホ?

Comment: @snailboat How about either? Since boo can be used for disappointment or sadness. Don't you think?

Comment: I think it's more along the lines of "boo hoo" rather than a ghost "boo" or a sports "boo" in the context. Regional thing? I've never heard it.

Comment: I always thought "boo" in this context was more expressing disapproval (the sports "boo") and not sadness, but now this is becoming a question about English.

Comment: How about [嫌]{いや}だ?

Comment: @jmac The "regional" thing could be that "boo hoo" is shortened to "boo". In which case wouldn't it be a duplicate of http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9656/questions-on-the-word-%E3%82%B7%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%82%AF? In which case I'll close my question =/

Comment: @Tek Even if it were boo hoo, I don't think it's a duplicate of that questions, as if you were to say シクシク at the beginning of a sentence the meaning would probably not be conveyed in the sense you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could say 「[トホホ](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%A8%E3%81%BB%E3%81%BB&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss)」.  It's a lot like "boo hoo".  I've heard that it's used more in fiction than in real life, but I think that's true of "boo hoo", too.

Chocolate pointed out on chat that you could also say 「[あーあ](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=3&p=%E3%81%82%E3%83%BC%E3%81%82)」.  Although I don't see entries for this interjection in any Japanese dictionaries, you can find it in Japanese-English dictionaries such as [edict](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E3%81%82%E3%83%BC%E3%81%82&eng=&dict=edict).  Edict describes it this way:

> oh no (used as an expression of despair or when giving up); sigh of boredom or disgust; oh boy

Another related word is 「[がっかり](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A&eng=&dict=edict)」.  Again, I'll quote edict:

> feel disappointed; dejected; lose heart; feel emotionally drained; feel let down

Edict lists more parts of speech for this word than Japanese dictionaries, so I decided to link to it here.  You can say, for example, `がっかりした` or `がっかりだ`.  I think you can also use it as an interjection, though the only place I could find listing it that way was [ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A&ref=sa): `がっかり！`

Answer (score 2):

I would say something like `イヤァァ〜` or `ワァ〜` should probably work OK.